# Three-level pricing for Laos visa extension / overstaying

Tags: price, laos, visa-extensions

On my last trip I was in Laos for six or seven weeks around September/October 2013 and extended my visa three times but can't remember the strange system of charges for the service.

I am sure there were three prices, depending on the situation, but can't remember exactly.

Something like:

- $1 USD per day if extending before your visa runs out ... I think ...
- $2 USD per day if ??? I forget ???
- $10 USD per day overstayed if you missed your exit date ... I think ...

Or maybe it was more like:

- $1 USD per day if extending at the immigration office before your visa runs out
- $5 USD per day overstayed if paying at the immigration office
- $10 USD per day overstayed when departing at an airport or border

I'm searching the Internet and my old social media updates for the details but can't find info on the three prices. Can somebody find the missing information?

Comment: That's what most Google hits are telling me but I'm positive I paid $1 per day on my last trip and actually knew the three different prices and what they were for at that time. \-:

Comment: [here](http://www.laos-guide-999.com/Laos-visa-extension.html) and [here](http://www.tourismlaos.org/show.php?Cont_ID=35) it says $2 if extended before visa runs out, $10 if after; plus some application and service fees.. both sites seems to agree - are you definite last time you paid $1?

Comment: Well I'm very sure but not quite 100% sure. I also talked to another traveller here who said she thought it was $2 but somebody more long term who she had met told her she always paid $1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [three](http://www.tourismlaos.org/show.php?Cont_ID=35) [different](http://www.laos-guide-999.com/Laos-visa-extension.html) [websites](http://www.travelfish.org/visas/laos), the pricing is as following:

- $2 per day to extend a valid visa
- $10 per day to extend an expired visa

It is possible that there is a $1/day option somewhere but I couldn't find any records of it.